# How to add custom app tasks in ubuntu activities search ? What is the specific term for that search bar?

Tags: 20.04, search, activities-overview

I have attached a screenshot as an example. I want to create my custom search option that executes specific scripts.

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These results are provided by a Gnome Shell search provider. From [Gnome Developper Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/search-provider.html):

> A search provider is a mechanism by which an application can expose its search capabilities to GNOME Shell. When the user types anything in the shell’s search entry, the text is forwarded to all known search providers, and the results are relayed back for display.

The [link](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/search-provider.html) introduces how a search provider is implemented.